# Put all rows from one table to another

Tags: mysql

how I can put all the rows from table A to table B witch all table have the same columns names

ex :

```
table A :
 x    y   z
 1    2   3
 4    5   6
 7    8   9

table B: 
x   y   z
10  11  12



table C should be like this :

x    y   z
1    2   3
4    5   6 
7    8   9
10   11  12
```

PS : I am using a query , I do'nt want to insert in a real table

Comment: Look up `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT` sub query. You can also use `SELECT INTO` to create table c if it doesn't exist. Your PS makes no sense to me. Could you please clarify by editing question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to select data from A and B, the `UNION` works:

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM A
  UNION SELECT x, y, z FROM B
```

If you want to insert data from A to B (which contradicts your P.S. but corresponds to your first sentence) then this is your solution:

```
INSERT into B SELECT * from A
```